# How to handle negative delays when predicting flight delays?

Tags: machine-learning, random-forest, preprocessing, normalization

I am working with the `nycflights dataset`. My goal is to predict departure and arrival time delays using `random forests`. My problem is that some flights have a *negative delay*, meaning they departed/arrived earlier than the scheduled time. So far, I have thought of 2 solutions to this:

- Dropping the rows with a negative delay and considering only the records with an actual delay.
- Replacing all the negative delays with the mean delay.

I am, however, worried that doing any of the above might have a negative impact on the prediction accuracy, since I am not taking into account the negative delays in any way.

What is the best way, in this case, to handle the negative values?

Comment: If I understand correctly, negative delay is just a measure for a plane arriving early, it is valid and meaningful. Is there a reason you don't want to keep negative delay measures as they are? Don't you want to predict if a plane arrives early?

Comment: Why don't you just leave the values as they are: negative? If at all, you could set them to zero, meaning "on time" (which is true when you treat it as binary problem).

Comment: I'm fairly new to ML so had some doubts about the negative values. But upon reading your answers and further inspection I decided to leave the negative delays as they are and proceed with them. Thank you!